# AJAX with Django in RESTful environment

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, mongodb, backbone.js

I am new in restful programing. I have a django website, my goal is to load part of the website asynchronously.

*By default what I do now is:*

call a url (e.g. `localhost:8080/index`) -> Routes the Django view -> View takes data from database (mongodb if you are curious) -> View gets the template -> Render all together and send back to browser

*What I want to improve is:*

When I have opened a url e.g. `localhost:8080/index` and I trigger an event (e.g. click a `<a>`) to send a request to my database and load other data.

*My question:*

What is the step I have to do to bridge the javascript / ajax with my mongodb safely?

Additionally I am considering to use a front end MCV framework (I think about backbone/I have limited knowledge as well) to handle the front-end requests. E.g. `localhost:8080/index#2` returns objects with `id : 2` of my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the following rest API frameworks for django. They will help save you a lot of time.

1. [**Django Tastypie**](http://tastypieapi.org/)
2. [**Django Rest Framework**](http://django-rest-framework.org/)

I have used both and personally like `tastypie` better. Once you have integrated one of these in your project you can use any front end javascript framework like `angularjs` or `backbone` or even not use one and simply make a call to the resource url to get the data via ajax.